# How do I pass record IDs from testSetup to isTest methods?

Tags: unit-test, test-setup, test-data-isolation

I want to create data in a test class that can be used by multiple test methods. However, for the test method to be able to access that test data, I need a way to pass the record IDs to from the `@TestSetup` method to the `@isTest` methods. Unfortunately, using static variables doesn't work- those get reset after the `@TestSetup` method.

Is there a way I can pass data like that?

Comment: You have asked an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) here.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that is possible today. The only way is through querying records in the test methods.

In the meanwhile you can upvote for the idea [Remember static variables set during testSetup annotated methods](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Dj51AAC)

Answer (score 1):

Salesforce has created @testSetup for data isolation from test class methods and this data once created can be utilized from all the methods.

It could not a good design if data to be created and passed to the `@isTest` methods which is used from testing.

Think about usage of testsetup method which can be used from multiple classes following this design where `TestDataFactory` class is reusable and that `setup()` method can be accessed from `@TestSetup` method of calling class.

```
public class FunctionalClass {
    //logic that needs to be tested

}

@IsTest
public class TestFunctionalClass {

    @TestSetup static void prepareData()
    {
        TestDataFactory.setup();
    }

    static testMethod void validateData()
    {
        //unit tests that test FunctionClass logic
        //query for data that is setup in TestDataFactory.class
    }

}

@IsTest
public class TestDataFactory {
    static void setup() {
        //insert test data
    }

    public static List<ExternalObject__x> getExternalObjectTestData() {
        //return mock external objects
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it is the best approacch. But I have used a text field that I can set a specific value for each test scenario. On the test method, I query using this text field.